# How to select records from multi-companies in Morphex reports?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta, ax

I want to know if I can select data from multi-company in Morphex reports, for example: user wants to get report's data from CEU & CEE companies. I don't mean get the whole data from all companies, I mean to get data from specific multi-companies.

I can achieve this in SSRS reports by passing a multi-value parameter to DATAAREAID table's field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems I can achieve this by set Report's Cross-Company property and QueryRun to yes.

```
this.query.allowCrossCompany(true);
this.query.addCompanyRang("CEU");
this.query.addCompanyRang("CEE");
```

Here are some links for more details:

[Cross-Company Reports in the AOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc588001%28v=AX.50%29.aspx)

[Cross-Company X++ Code Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc518738%28v=AX.50%29.aspx)